# Airflow - can't launch scheduler at given port

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

When I'm trying to perform `airflow scheduler` CLI command to run airflow scheduler (locally), and keep getting error of `Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8794)`. No scheduler process is running, but the port seems to be in use. Did someone have this problem and can help me?

Comment: you might ran the scheduler in a different terminal. if you are in linux run "ps aux | grep airflow", and check if you have another process running already

Comment: @ozs Thanks, indeed this was an issue. Also, If someone wants to delete usages on a given port - this is a command that helped me: kill $(lsof -t -i:{your-port})